# Elastic Search with Docker compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I tried to bring up ES cluster with one node by ingesting some variables,it seems all the variables are not ingested. Is it issue with the syntax or that is how it works ?

Here is the compose file ( stripped down version)

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.12
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - node.name=elasticsearch1
```

However, i see only `cluster.name` is ingested.

```
training@training-virtualbox:~/playArea$ docker container exec -it elasticsearch1 sh
sh-4.2# cd config
sh-4.2# cat elasticsearch.
elasticsearch.keystore  elasticsearch.yml       
sh-4.2# cat elasticsearch.yml 
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to check your variables in container by command `export`

```
docker exec elasticsearch1 bash -c "export"
```

Comment: you mean all the variables are ingested ?

Comment: Yep. Defined variables in docker-compose  do not overwrite values ​​in files. They are used in  environment variables.

Comment: I admit that some services create a configuration file with new values ​​before starting. 
But this is not necessary at all.

Comment: makes sense, that is what i was looking for the experts to understand what are those values

Comment: I checked your image elasticsearch:6.8.12. Cluster.name: "docker-cluster" - default value in elasticsearch.yml.

Comment: you are actually correct, i will remove the comment

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems those variables are dynamically ingested as part of script

```
elastic+       1       0 25 06:30 ?        00:04:30 /opt/jdk-14.0.1+7/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1ReservePercent=25 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30 -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-17045455673122852465 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=data -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -XX:UseAVX=2 -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/ -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config -Des.distribution.flavor=default -Des.distribution.type=docker -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Ecluster.name=docker-cluster -Ediscovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1,elasticsearch2 -Enode.name=elasticsearch1 -Ediscovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=2 -Ebootstrap.memory_lock=true
```